# How to setup a lot of domain names in one row?

Tags: statistics, google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I am working on a blog factory and we let the final user to use a fully customized domain name like `www.myawsomeblog.com`. There is a lot of people using this feature, so we cannot do a per case treatments.

How we can tag our pages in a way that we can track traffic for each domains without pain? Even if, the traffic statistics is a little mess is not a big deal as soon as there is a way to see which domain have which traffic.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would want a profile for each site, but you would have to manually set each new one up.  But it sounds like you want to avoid that...

The easiest but least flexible way to do it would be to pop your _trackPageview with the full URL so it shows the subdomain instead of just path, in pages reports.  But that puts all of your sites into a single profile, and there's no easy automated way to segment them (you can, but it's manual, esp since you have arbitrary domains popping up).

Alternatively if you don't wanna mess with having to change existing code, you can setup a [domain prefix filter](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55503) for your profile, to rewrite the page name to have domain prefix.. but that still gives you same problem as above. You can filter your reports to see 
the different domains, but they won't be in aggregated buckets.  You will have to basically export to excel and do some manual grouping/filtering there, would be easiest.